# Perform Rolling Sum Based on Another Column's Value in Excel Table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs, excel-tables

I'm looking to perform a **rolling** sum for an excel table based on the value of a column.

I want the sum only up to the current row (not sum of all rows that have the same value)

**I've made a simple example to explain:**

I want to use table references in a formula to get the item-wise rolling sum for the first 2 columns in the table below. 'Item' and 'Value' are known ; 'Item_Wise_Rolling_Sum' is to be calculated

| Item | Value | Item_Wise_Rolling_Sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 1 |
| a | 2 | 3 |
| b | 10 | 10 |
| b | 5 | 15 |
| b | 2 | 17 |
| c | 6 | 6 |

I tried to use the following formula to no avail:

```
=SUMIFS(MyTable[[#Headers],[Value]]:[@Value], [Item], [@Item])
```

The idea was to calculate sum uptill the current row only, not for all rows below.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For older versions try using <kbd>SUMIFS()</kbd>

[image]

---

```
=SUMIFS(B$2:B2,A$2:A2,A2)
```

---

Or, In `MS365` try using <kbd>MAP()</kbd>

[image]

---

```
=MAP(A2:A7,B2:B7,LAMBDA(x,y,SUM((A2:x=x)*B2:y)))
```

---

Or, using <kbd>SUMIF()</kbd> with `Structured References`

[image]

---

```
=SUMIF(MyTable[[#Headers],[Item]]:[@Item],[@Item],MyTable[[#Headers],[Value]]:[@Value])
```

---

With <kbd>SUMIFS()</kbd> need to change the ranges correctly as per the parameters,

```
=SUMIFS(MyTable[[#Headers],[Value]]:[@Value],MyTable[[#Headers],[Item]]:[@Item],[@Item])
```

---

Another alternative way of anchoring and using <kbd>SUMIFS()</kbd> for running total in Excel Tables: (Comparatively Shorter Method)

[image]

---

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX([Value],1):[@Value],INDEX([Item],1):[@Item],[@Item])
```

---

As commented by **[JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv)** Sir, alternative approach using <kbd>MAP()</kbd> if in future you think of not using `Structured References` then try the below.

```
=MAP(A2:A7,B2:B7,LAMBDA(x,y,SUMIF(A2:x,x,B2:y)))
```

---

Comment: Maybe `=MAP(A2:A7,B2:B7,LAMBDA(x,y,SUMIF(A2:x,x,B2:y)))` with `SUMIF()` is more intuitive?

Comment: But how do i make that work in excel tables I saw later OP wanted using Structured references

Comment: Then other methods is better. I just responded about the `MAP()` approach.

Comment: @JvdV Sir, but it is helpful for future reference, Sir posted

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I used the one with Structured References and it worked!

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if another answer is necessary, but you can also just use the current row:

```
=SUM([Value]*(ROW()>=ROW([Value]))*([Item]=[@Item]))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll definitely try it out soon!

Answer (score 4):

Using table references:
`=SUMIF(MyTable[[#Headers],[Item]]:[@Item],[@Item],MyTable[[#Headers],[Value]]:[@Value])`

[image]

Comment: Sir same answer, posted already!

Comment: Lol, it was not edited in yet when I started writing my answer.

Comment: Sir 8 mins back!

Comment: Yes, creating an answer on my mobile phone and taking screenshots + editing the table name in the formula= 8 min.

Comment: Nevermind sir, I have another alternative posted for Excel Tables. With `SUMIFS()` & `INDEX()`

Comment: Nice one using INDEX